# Hololens emulator verify the project is selected to be deployed in the solution configuration manager

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, uwp, visual-studio-2017, hololens

First I was having hard time to add Hololens emulator in my visual studio 2017 community then with the help of a post that said it require VS 2015 updater 3 I was able to see at least emulator in my VS. Now I am facing deployment issue, before anyone suggest links from stackoverflow I have tried everything that is already here, So I need a new approach.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you deploy?

Comment: I don't have a device. Also I have already clicked the checkmark for deploy in configuration manager, let me add its screenshot

Comment: any clue...I have already spent more than 10 hours just trying to see the emulator on VS now its not running.

Comment: Also try to install mobile emulator which will help in differentiate problem , and can you check to install in ARM configuration. I haven't  physical device but i think it is ARM based

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think I should have posted the solution sooner.
Well, it was the visual studio version that was not supporting. So once I rolled back to 2015 everything worked just fine.

Thanks, everyone who took time to look into my question.